# Woocommerce category description as subtitle

Tags: plugins, categories

I'd love to place the category description just after the main title in a span, like a subtitle.

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_page_title', function ($title) {
    // what should be here?

    $title .= "<span class='subtitle'>{$description}</span>";
    return $title;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra hook you can use for this `woocommerce_archive_description`, hook into it like this:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'wc_category_description' );
    function wc_category_description() {
        if ( is_product_category() ) {
            global $wp_query;
            $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
            $cat_desc = term_description( $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
            $subtit = '<span class="subtitle">'.$cat_desc.'</span>';
            echo $subtit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your archive-product.php template:

```
<span class="subtitle">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>
</span>
```