# Can't show Woocommerce product category description

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to show product category description on a Woocommerce pdf invoice. Here i'm using this code , but not showing anything.

```
$cat_id  = $category->term_id;
$term = get_term( $cat_id, 'term', true );
$description = $term->description;
```

Sample output:

```
$t.=".$description.";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: As @MarkKaplun suggested, you have to use the correct taxonomy, so `product_cat`. There is a function [`term_description()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description) you could use, you might want to take a look at an [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116796/22534) I gave some time ago to pretty much the same topic.

Comment: Note: In regards to close voting this question, this is about getting the description from a custom taxonomy, so strictly core functionality related, thus IMHO not worthy of closing as not WordPress related.

Comment: See I've successfully got woocommerce category thumbnail using this: `$idcat = $ticket_cat['category_id'];`  `$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $idcat, 'thumbnail_id', true );`   `$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );` Any suggestion?

Comment: @ialocin, i've tried it. nothing happened. It showed blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will probably work for post categories, but you need to specify the right taxonomy in the call to `get_term` to fetch the product category (which is what I assume you want to get). But actually if your `$category` actually contains the product category then I am not sure you even need to call `get_term` as the description is probably part of the category object.

Comment: I've successfully got woocommerce category thumbnail using this: `$idcat = $ticket_cat['category_id']; `
 `$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $idcat, 'thumbnail_id', true ); `
 `$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );` Any suggestion?